# Difference between iwconfig and nmcli

Tags: wireless, network-manager, nmcli

When I run the command

```
nmcli dev wifi
```

in my console I get the list of wifi networks, including the one I'm connected to

```
*  SSID                  MODE   CHAN  RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   
*  eduroam               Infra  36    54 Mbit/s  63      ▂▄▆_  WPA2 802.1X
```

This seems to suggest that the maximum transfer speed is 54Mb/s. However,

```
$ iwconfig 
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"eduroam"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: 30:D1:7E:EE:30:F1   
          Bit Rate=117 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:60   Missed beacon:0
```

suggests a bit rate of 117 Mb/s. Doing a quick speed test, the 117 Mb/s is closer to the truth. In fact, `nmcli` never reports a speed greater than 54 Mb/s regardless of the network.

- What's the difference between `nmcli` and `iwconfig`?
- Why does `nmcli` report a lower speed?

---

- Ubuntu version: 15.05

Comment: Have you checked them in same time? Try `watch -n1 "iwconfig;nmcli dev wifi"`  see if they follow.

Comment: The bit rate under `nmcli` is always 54 Mb/s (Regardless of the network).

Comment: For me it's the same output in `iwconfig` and `nmcli dev wifi`. Could be a bug. What Ubuntu version you got by the way ?

Comment: Ubuntu: version 15.05